# Selecting values from a 3-column dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a 3-dimensional array, the variables being x, y and z. x is a list of places, y is a list of time, and z is a list of names. The list of names do not start at the same initial time across the places:

```
x   y   z
x1  1   NA
x1  2   z2
x1  3   z3
x1  4   z1
x2  1   NA
x2  2   NA
x2  3   z5
x2  4   z3
x3  1   z3
x3  2   z1
x3  3   z2
x3  4   z2
```

How do I find the first z for every x? I want the output matrix or dataframe to be:

```
x  z
x1 z2
x2 z5
x3 z3
```

Comment: please provide some sample data, as I have no clue how your array looks like exactly. As far as it looks now, you have a simple matrix, not a 3D-array as data structure.

Comment: Is there any way to upload a sample data?

Comment: Make a small reproducible example using `matrix()` or try `dput(your.data)`.

Comment: Okay, I just edited the original post including the sample data.

Comment: now it looks like a dataframe (which is 2-dimensional, see the introduction to R for some examples on arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED, after example data was supplied**

You can use function `ddply()` in package `plyr`

```
dat <- "x   y   z
x1  1   NA
x1  2   z2
x1  3   z3
x1  4   z1
x2  1   NA
x2  2   NA
x2  3   z5
x2  4   z3
x3  1   z3
x3  2   z1
x3  3   z2
x3  4   z2"

df <- read.table(textConnection(dat), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(x), function(x)x[!is.na(x$z), ][1, "z"])

   x V1
1 x1 z2
2 x2 z5
3 x3 z3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use plyr

```
t(data.frame(lapply(split(df, as.factor(df$x)), function(k) head(k$z[!is.na(k$z)], 1))))

   [,1]
x1 "z2"
x2 "z5"
x3 "z3"
```